# Split function in Spotfire 7.5.0.79 version

Tags: split, calculated-columns, spotfire

I'm using Spotfire 7.5.0.79 version. I want to split a column based on a special character. I do not find Split function in Spotfire as described in the below link.

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/7.8.0/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire-analyst_UsersGuide/data/data_splitting_a_column.htm

Example: Sunny Jayadev <1234568@54652>

I want result as Sunny Jayadev. So, "<" special character will be separator.

Comment: would the other column have <1234568@54652> or 1234568@54652

Comment: @scsimon Second column is not required. I need only first column

Comment: Did this work out for you Sunny?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with that function, but you can use this as a calculated column. The docs are for 7.8. Maybe this is a new feature that isn't in 7.5

```
left([column1],Find("<",[column1]) - 1)
```